Can't scroll UIScrollView after adding several images
I have trouble with a UIScrollView in UIKit. This is my code. I want my screen to be able to scroll to see all elements.
I can't scroll in my app. What's happening?
I want it to scroll vertically. How can I use UIScrollView in this situation? Can I use another way to scroll my view?
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var image: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return image
    }()
    private var image1: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return image
    }()
    private var image2: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return image
    }()
    private var image3: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return image
    }()
    private var image4: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return image
    }()      
    private var scroll: UIScrollView = {
       let scroll = UIScrollView()
        scroll.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return scroll
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(scroll)
        
        scroll.addSubview(image)
        scroll.addSubview(image1)
        scroll.addSubview(image2)
        scroll.addSubview(image3)
        scroll.addSubview(image4)
        scroll.addSubview(image5)

        let imagetest = UIImage(named: "test")
        image.image = imagetest
        image1.image = imagetest
        image2.image = imagetest
        image3.image = imagetest
        image4.image = imagetest

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scroll.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            scroll.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
            scroll.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
            scroll.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
            
            image.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.leadingAnchor),
            image.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.trailingAnchor),
            image.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.topAnchor, constant: 20),
            image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            image.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.widthAnchor),
    
            
            image1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.leadingAnchor),
            image1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.trailingAnchor),
            image1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            image1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            image1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.widthAnchor),
            image1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.widthAnchor),

            
            image2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.leadingAnchor),
            image2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.trailingAnchor),
            image2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image1.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            image2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            image2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.widthAnchor),

            
            image3.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.leadingAnchor),
            image3.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.trailingAnchor),
            image3.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image2.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            image3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            image3.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.widthAnchor),

            
            image4.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.leadingAnchor),
            image4.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.trailingAnchor),
            image4.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image3.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            image4.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            image4.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.widthAnchor),
        ])     
    }
}


UIScrollView has two special layout guides you should use: frameLayoutGuide and contentLayoutGuide. The former is used to size and position the scroll view itself. The latter is used to size and position the content within the scroll view.
Update your constraints to the following to make it work as desired:
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    // Size and position the scroll view within the view controller
    scroll.frameLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
    scroll.frameLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
    scroll.frameLayoutGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
    scroll.frameLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),

    // Ensure content view width is the same width as the scrollview
    scroll.contentLayoutGuide.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor),

    // Size and position the image within the content view
    image.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
    image.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
    image.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20),
    image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),

    image1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
    image1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
    image1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
    image1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),

    image2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
    image2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
    image2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image1.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
    image2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),

    image3.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
    image3.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
    image3.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image2.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
    image3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),

    image4.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
    image4.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
    image4.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image3.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
    image4.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -20),
    image4.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
])

All of the images set their horizontal position to the leading and trailing anchors of the content guide. This implicitly gives each image its width so there is no need to also set the image width.
The top of the first image is anchored to the top of the content guide.
The bottom of the last image is anchored to the bottom of the content guide.
The width of the content guide is set to the scroll view's width so there is no horizontal scrolling.

Hmm... seems a bit of an uncommon way to use scroll view constraints. In general, UIKit provides the .frameLayoutGuide based on the scroll view's frame, not the other way around. Also uncommon to set .contentLayoutGuide.widthAnchor ... note that in Storyboard / Interface Builder, you cannot do either of those.

@DonMag I've never taken a poll so I have no idea how common my usage is. :) But it works just fine and I find it very intuitive. Your approach works too but I find it less obvious. You constrain content to both the content guide and the frame guide. I only constrain content to the content guide (and other content). And in a case like this, I constrain one dimension of the content guide to the frame guide. Clean separation of roles. I also never use storyboards so I can't comment on what limitations Xcode causes for setting up constraints.

Read up on UIScrollView and .contentLayoutGuide and .frameLayoutGuide
In order to be "scrollable" the constraints on the UI elements must define the scrollable content area.
Easiest way to manage and understand that is to declare two properties:
    let cg = scroll.contentLayoutGuide
    let fg = scroll.frameLayoutGuide

and then constrain the elements to those guides:
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        scroll.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
        scroll.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
        scroll.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
        scroll.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
        
        // controls the Top of the scrollable region
        image.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.topAnchor, constant: 20),
        // controls the Leading of the scrollable region
        image.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.leadingAnchor),
        // controls the Trailing - and thus the Width - of the scrollable region
        image.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.trailingAnchor),

        image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
        image.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fg.widthAnchor),
        
        
        image1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.leadingAnchor),
        
        // we only need trailing anchor on the widest content element
        //image1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.trailingAnchor),
        
        image1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
        image1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
        image1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fg.widthAnchor),
        
        
        image2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.leadingAnchor),
        
        // we only need trailing anchor on the widest content element
        //image2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.trailingAnchor),
        
        image2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image1.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
        image2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
        image2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fg.widthAnchor),
        
        
        image3.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.leadingAnchor),
        
        // we only need trailing anchor on the widest content element
        //image3.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.trailingAnchor),
        
        image3.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image2.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
        image3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
        image3.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fg.widthAnchor),
        
        
        image4.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.leadingAnchor),
        
        // we only need trailing anchor on the widest content element
        //image4.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.trailingAnchor),
        
        image4.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image3.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
        image4.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
        image4.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fg.widthAnchor),
        
        // controls the Bottom - and thus the Height - of the scrollable region
        image4.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.bottomAnchor),
    ])

